# Creating binary external resource file in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, rcc

I need to create binary external resource file due to the fact that I'm working with multiple large images. I tried to create it from the commandline in Qt Creator as stated in the documentation (with `rcc -binary image.qrc -o image.rcc` command, where image.qrc is my already created .qrc file, also located in the working directory), but so far without a luck.

If I understand correctly, running application with this command should generate image.rcc file in the working directory, right? Currently, when I run my application, it starts but file isn't created anywhere. There is no error, no nothing. I would appreciciate anyones help, because I run out of ideas.

I use Qt 5.8 and MinGW 32bit compiler (but tried it also with MSVC2010 32bit and Qt 5.4.2 and still without success).

EDIT:
My qrc file (I reduced the number of files just for the tests).

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>images/dm.png</file>
        <file>images/mountains_op.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: show your .qrc file

Comment: Done. I forgot to include it before, sorry!

Comment: Run the following command and tell me what message you get: `rcc -binary image.qrc -o image.rcc --verbose`

Comment: Yeah, I found the solution. Thanks, your suggestion pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (mostly thanks to @eyllanesc comment).  I needed to change the directory in the command line to the one where rcc.exe is located. I kept trying to run: `rcc -binary image.qrc -o image.rcc` from the working directory of my project and not from the directory of Qt, where rcc.exe actually is.